# Error with window hierarchy when logging out and logging back in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement GoogleSignIn to my iOS app and I have it authenticating and logging the users in but when I log them out and try to log back in I am getting the error "Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController on LoginViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Here is where I sign them in in the AppDelegate:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if(snapshot == nil){
                self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("username").setValue(user?.displayName)
                self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(user?.email)

                let imageUrl = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 400).absoluteString
                self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(imageUrl)
            }
            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signIn_Segue", sender: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

And here is how I log them out and go back to the Start View Controller:

```
@IBAction func logout_Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    do{
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    } catch let logoutError{
        print(logoutError)
    }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I think a better way would be to replace the `rootViewController` with the `LoginViewController` or the `StartViewController` depending on the state but since you are presenting the `LoginViewController` then why don't you dismiss it when logging in instead

Comment: So I should just dismiss instead of performing the "signIn_Segue" in the AppDelegate?

Comment: self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)

Comment: You should make your rootViewController  = startViewController. And inside the startVC check if there is user or not. If there is no user, present your login VC. And in login VC, if user log in, dismiss login view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is bad Approach to present login View controller in Logout Method. you need to reset App after log out. to do this

1. if you have presented log out view Controller (the view controller in which you have logout @IBaction method) then dismiss it
2. set rootViewController to LoginViewController.

this code may be helpful,

```
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    let LoginUpViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appdelegate.window?.rootViewController = LoginUpViewController
```

or you can change according to your need. changing root to another View Controller will kill previous View Controller along with its child, so your app will completely reset.